# Changing Format of Date Field in ArcMap Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, date

I am trying to change the format of date field using ArcMap field calculator.

My data is currently in the format "%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s" (e.g. 5/05/2016 12:25:46 AM)

I want to change this to "%d/%m/%Y" (e.g. 5/05/2016). No time data.

I have been trying to use the following, but this does not work.

```
datetime.strptime( !DateField!, "%d/%m/%Y)
```

I have looked at several similar questions posted, but none seem to do this?

Python or VBScript is ok, using ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Was this one of the "several similar questions posted" that you looked at?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165892/using-arcgis-desktop-field-calculator-python-to-parse-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for python, just use the [Convert Time Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm) tool!

Answer (score 3):

The dates are stored as strings (to be precise, unicode) meaning that you need to construct a true Python `datetime` object and then manipulate it.

If my date field `MyDate` is `2017-08-09 08:51:32`, then I'd use this snippet

`str(datetime.datetime.strptime(!MyDate!, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date())` to get `2017-08-09`.

If your date is `5/05/2016 12:25:46 AM`, you would need to use

`str(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").date())` to get `5/05/2016`